# image displaying issue

Tags: php, html

I have an image url but there is not image or the image name has been renamed, so i am not able to view the image in this case i want to show a default custom image. any idea on how to do it

thanks in advance

Comment: is the image on your server or is it an external url?

Comment: So you have a url to an image but there is no image there? You can use the error event of an image which will raise if the image src specified does not return an image to be displayed. Then if that event is raised you can change the src to your default one.

Answer (score 0):

if the file is located on your server

```
<?php
$filename = '/path/to/file.jpg';

if (!file_exists($filename)) {
    $filename = '/path/to/default.jpg'
} 
?>
```

otherwise you can try using `GetImageSize`

```
if(@GetImageSize($remoteImageURL)){
        //image exists!
}
```

Comment: I'd be excited to have such a silly lamer who hotlink to my site and use that code. they'd never have this page displayed

Comment: agreed but that wasn't the scope of the question ;)

Comment: it will be killing overhead anyway. I hope you aren't one who recommend to use a single quote instead of double in sake of performance optimization

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same site, you can use any of PHP filesystem functions to see if an image file still on it's place. `is_readable()` is my favorite one for that purpose.
Sure, not URL but a filesystem path should be used.

If it's just a hotlinks to other sites - forget it. You can't check it for reasonable price.

Answer (score 0):

if the image is one your server ie. if you know the path to the image file, you can use the php function  `file_exists`

```
if (file_exists($imageFilePath)){
   $url = $imageUrl;
} else {
   $url = $customImageUrl;
}
```